# PHP: Can attribute values in one class be transferred to attributes in another class with the same name?

Tags: php, instantiation, cloning

I am accidentally sort of making my own framework. (Before you start pls see PS at end!)

So for example I have:

```
class MessageSchedule
{
  use Utility;
  protected $messageScheduleID;
  protected $messageScheduleName;
  ...
  protected $minDaysPerWeek = 7;
  protected $maxDaysPerWeek = 3;
  protected $currentTimeZone = "Pacific/Honolulu";
}

class MessageSendList
{
  use Utility;
  protected $messageSendListID = NULL;
  protected $messageScheduleID = NULL;
  protected $messageScheduleName = NULL;
  ...
  protected $currentTimeZone = NULL;
}
```

All tables in the database have mirrored classes with EXACTLY the same names for variables and attributes. Now in my Utility traits I have functions to do CRUD and to read an instantiated object into a script as a key/value array which I can then `extract`.

Using the calculated attribute names of any class I can do a quick (and very dirty) population of an an object with a `foreach` loop implementing sort of...

```
$thisThing = new Thing;
$thisThing -> setThisValue = $thisValue;
... etc
```

I can do it that way BUT it would be less error prone if I could just sort of "clone if attributes there" function in PHP. Sort of:

```
$thisFoo = new Foo;
$thisBar = new Bar;
$thisOne = $thisFoo->doCreat(12); //Instantiates Foo with values from FooID=12
$thisBar = partialClone($thisOne); // If PHP had a partial clone! That is what I am looking for.
```

In  my case it would copy over the values of `$messageScheduleID $messageScheduleName and $timeZone` into a new instance of `MessageSendList`.

Hope that is vaguely comprehensible.

Thanks. Steve

... Later:  This is what I am currently using and trying to replace.

```
$thisSendList = new MessageSendList();
$vars = $thisSendList->classAttributes();//Generic find attribute name
foreach ($vars as $var)
{
  if (isset($$var))
  {
    $thisSendList -> doSet($var, $$var); // Generic set attributes
  }
}
$thisSendList -> doCreate();
```

PS OK I **KNOW** that I **SHOULD** be using Laravel or some such but the learning curve there is pretty steep. I already have to use jQuery, PHP, SQL, HTML, CSS, phpStorm (almost a programming language in itself) etc. etc.

I am a pretty good (very slow) programmer and I can code anything and once I have done it I understand it. One day I will probably move to Laravel but, for the moment, it is a step too far for me ... and I know someome will still say "Why not use Yi" or whatever. I am 64, no memory (far too much cannabis) so...

Comment: Wouldn't dependency injection be an option here? Give `MessageSchedule` instance as a parameter of `MessageSendList `?

Comment: Daan thanks that looks too clever for me. My fudge works so going for something I am not familiar with (unless just a simple core PHP function) is likely to cause me more problems.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ReflectionClass` to get array of public properties, than use `array_intersect` of those arrays to get list of properties that you should copy.

```php
function getPropertyList($object)
{
    $reflection = new ReflectionClass($object);
    $properties = $reflection->getProperties(ReflectionProperty::IS_PUBLIC);
    $result = [];
    foreach ($properties as $property) {
        $result[] = $property->getName();
    }
    return $result;
}

$thisFoo = new Foo;
$thisBar = new Bar;
$thisOne = $thisFoo->doCreat(12); //Instantiates Foo with values from FooID=12
$propsFoo = getPropertyList($thisOne);
$propsBar = getPropertyList($thisBar);
$common = array_intersect($propsFoo, $propsBar);
foreach ($common as $property) {
    $thisBar->$property = $thisOne->$property;
}
```

You can turn this functionality into trait that you would use in classes where you need it.

Resources:

- [ReflectionClass::getProperties()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getproperties.php)
- [array_intersect()](https://www.php.net/array_intersect)

Comment: Michal thanks for that but not really any cleaner than what I am already doing (and confused the heck out of me). So suspect will be carrying on with my fudge. Thanks for the input. Will put RefClass on my study list.